# How to make a forever loop in JS not freeze

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm working on a block based programming language based of of Google's Blockly. I need to make a block that loops the contents forever, for making games.

I tried a while (true) loop but it froze. Is there any way to make a forever loop that won't freeze and will let other scripts run?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: Don't you know that infinite loops are not recommended? https://flexiple.com/javascript/infinite-loops-javascript/

Comment: Have a read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: A `sync` infinite loop is not possible, but an `async` one is.

Comment: @Keith although correct, I'd not encourage that pattern. Imo. using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) or even [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) would be the better choice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `setTimeout()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Something like that to loop indefinitely without blocking the main thread (you should probably design a way to break the loop at some point) :

```
function doSomeStuff() {
  // do some stuff…
  setTimeout(() => {
    doSomeStuff();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(doSomeStuff, 1000);` the arrow function doesn't add any value to the code.